# Best way to download multiple image from a remote server with PHP

Tags: php

I've been having a bit of trouble downloading a large number of files from a remove server via http at the kind of speed I need. In this situation I need to get images, up to 250 groups of up to 36 images (usually less). I've tried both using get_file_contents and copy(), both work but are slow, in a single run of 20 group it tikes minutes, when all is said and done this will have to be run for 200 sets, of up to 200 groups, of up to 36 images.

Is there any speedier ways to download that many images using PHP?

Comment: Is this a PHP problem or a bandwidth problem?

Comment: What sort of throughput are you getting? If you think the remote server might be throttling individual connections, you might get a faster total time by kicking off several downloads. Is the remote server under your control?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Curl download of 2.5k+ files too slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848048/curl-download-of-2-5k-files-too-slow) - This might not directly answer your question but shed some light into your issue. Look for a download client PHP class that handles multiple file-downloads in parallel. Some of those exist based on the `curl` extension.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a *nix server, try using a call to `wget` instead of calling get_file_contents/copy as I would think this would be a more efficient way of downloading the images (just guessing here).

As mentioned in the comments, it could also be a bandwidth issue from either your server or from the remote server. These are out of the scope of stackoverflow and you would be better posting on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)